# « Malgré que » est-il correct ?

Tags: grammaire, standard

> Malgré qu'il ait beaucoup travaillé, il a raté son examen.

On entend souvent l'emploi de *malgré que* dans ce genre de tournure. Est-ce correct ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

L'Académie Française [recommande](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#48_strong-em-malgr-que-em-strong) d'éviter l'emploi de "malgré que" comme subordonnant de concession. Cet emploi relève généralement d'une confusion entre conjonction de subordination et préposition.

On préférera employer la **conjonction de subordination** "bien que" :

> Bien qu'il ait beaucoup travaillé, il a raté son examen.

Ou encore la conjonction de subordination "quoique" :

> Quoiqu'il ait beaucoup travaillé, il a raté son examen.

Ou bien encore la **préposition** "malgré" :

> Malgré ses efforts, il a raté son examen.

Comment: Au risque de paraître insistant, lire [la discussion sur meta](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/11/82) pour ce qui est de la correction.

Comment: @Evpok J'ai modéré la réponse.

Comment: Parfait, merci :)

Comment: Je ne partage pas la remarque d'Evpok. Comme l'indique la discussion sur Meta, _Tout contributeur est libre d'être prescriptif ou descriptif dans ses réponses._ En l'occurence, aucune source n'indique que "malré que" est correct (à l'exception du _malgré que j'en aie_), je suis donc d'accord avec la première version de la réponse à savoir: c'est une erreur, il ne faut pas l'employer.

Comment: Une règle de grammaire désuète. N'importe quoi !

Comment: @rds Une source l'indique : http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2935. Toute affirmation à l'effet que c'est une faute ou que ce n'est pas correct est fausse.

Answer (score 14):

D'abord, il y a une expression figée qui utilise « malgré que » de manière consensuelle : « malgré que j'en aie » (que tu en aies, etc.). Cette expression signifie « en dépit de moi », « malgré moi ». Elle est vieillie ; de nos jours, il faut la considérer comme très soutenue et potentiellement incomprise.

En dehors de ce cas, les dictionnaires prescriptifs considèrent en général « malgré que » comme un usage incorrect. Dans le Dictionnaire de l'Académie française, « malgré que » n'apparaît pas (sauf dans l'usage très particulier ci-dessus). [Littré](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littr%C3%A9) [remarque](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=malgre):

> *Malgré que*, dans tout autre emploi que celui qui est indiqué ci-dessus, serait une faute ; et l'on ne peut dire : « malgré qu'il ait agi ainsi », « pour quoiqu'il ait agi ainsi ». La raison en est que *malgré que* veut dire *mauvais gré que*, *quelque mauvais gré que*.

Cela n'empêche pas les dictionnaires descriptifs de recenser des usages. Le Petit Robert note qu'il s'agit d'un « emploi critiqué ». Le [Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/malgr%C3%A9) indique

> locution considérée comme incertaine par les puristes, même suivie du subjonctif; se rencontre exceptionnellement avec l'indicatif dans l'usage oral

Le TLF cite un usage remontant au 18e siècle. L'usage tend à se répandre avec le temps.

En pratique, l'incorrection de « malgré que » est suffisamment connue pour que l'on courre fortement le risque d'être repris si on l'utilise. Cela n'empêche pas de l'entendre (et dans une moindre mesure de la lire) à l'occasion.

Il faut donc considérer « malgré que » comme non standard, mais potentiellement en voie de le devenir. C'est en tout cas à déconseiller dans une rédaction ou à un locuteur non natif.

Comment: Exemple d'usage "autorisé" de la locution malgré que :  *Il n'a pas refusé de me rendre ce service et il l'a fait, malgré qu'il en ait.* (peu importe la réticence qu'il avait).

Comment: @Yves C'est l'expression figée *malgré qu'il en ait* que je mentionne dans mon premier paragraphe. C'est un cas à part.

Answer (score 7):

Non, ce n'est pas une tournure correcte - voir http://www.synapse-fr.com/manuels/MALGRE.htm

Il vaut mieux dire : "bien qu'il ait beaucoup travaillé, il a raté son examen" et, à la rigueur, "malgré le fait qu'il ait beaucoup travaillé, il a raté son examen".

Answer (score 2):

Je n'ai pas mon vieux Grevisse sur moi, donc je me contente pour l'instant de citer quelqu'un le citant, mais de mémoire, son propos (et surtout les patronymes qu'il cite, sont conformes à sa pensée):

> malgré que était d’usage courant dans le français classique (XVIIe
>   siècle). Grevisse (*le Bon Usage*, 13e éd., § 1091-1093) estime qu’il
>   était peut-être d’usage populaire, mais que la locution a perdu ce
>   caractère. Il cite d’ailleurs maints exemples tirés des meilleurs
>   auteurs, appuyés parfois par l’imparfait du subjonctif (il ne s’agit
>   donc pas de mettre seulement un « parler populaire » dans la bouche
>   d’un personnage) : chez Maupassant, Barrès (ne fut-il pas de
>   l’Académie ?), Anatole France (qui y fut la caution de gauche, sans
>   doute. Mais c’est un auteur français dont la langue à la fois claire
>   et pure a su se mettre au service de bien des causes justes, dont la
>   dreyfusiste... et qui fut, on l’ignore trop souvent, couronné du prix
>   Nobel de Littérature), Proust, Mauriac, Cocteau).
>
> Hanse, pour sa part (*Nouveau Dictionnaire des difficultés du Français
>   moderne*), relève plus simplement que « malgré que, loc[ution]
>   conj[onctive], condamné avec obstination par les puristes, est
>   incontestablement correct au sens de bien que et est suivi du
>   subjonctif. »

[(Luc Bentz, 1998.)](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article38)

Je tâcherai de retrouver ça dans mon exemplaire, d'ailleurs plus ancien.

---

**ÉDITION:** paragraphe 978, dans mon édition de 1959 (7e édition). Daudet, Barrès, Régnier, Gourmont, Prévost, Proust, Colette, Mauriac, Romains, Bourget, Bordeaux (entre autres) emploient l'expression. Et de citer Gide, *Incidences*, p. 73-74 :

> J’ai écrit, avec Proust et Barrès, et ne rougirai pas d’écrire encore:
>   malgré que, estimant que, si l’expression était fautive hier, elle a
>   cessé de l’être. Elle ne se confond pas avec bien que, qui n’indique
>   qu’une résistance passive ; elle indique une opposition.
>   Outre les questions de sonorité, l'affaire me semble entendue: non, il n'y a pas d'erreur à employer ce tour.

Comment: Merci pour cette précision !

Answer (score 0):

Malgré ou malgré que ?

Malgré est une préposition signifiant :

```
contre le gré de quelqu'un
en dépit de quelque chose
```

[Source](http://grammaire.cordial-enligne.fr/manuels/MALGRE.htm)