# malgré / malgré que / en depit de

Tags: grammaire, standard

I'm a little bit confused as to which one to use in this case, since I can't seem to find one definite answer (specifically on whether **malgré que** is incorrect or not) and therefore I'm stuck right now. I'm trying to say:

> One thing I really liked about this book was the message that despite something being vulnerable, small and seemingly defenceless...

And here's what I thought it could be:

> Une chose que j'ai bien aimé dans ce livre a été le message que malgré que quelque chose soit vulnérable, petit ou apparemment impuissant...

But the problem is that I've found two different opinions on *malgré que*. First being on [SE](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/202/malgr%C3%A9-que-est-il-correct):

> L'Académie Française recommande d'éviter l'emploi de "malgré que" comme subordonnant de concession. Cet emploi relève généralement d'une confusion entre conjonction de subordination et préposition.

Which agrees with the recommendation given by [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/malgr%C3%A9)

> Littré et les grammairiens puristes n'acceptent ***malgré que*** que dans l'emploi II A, qui n'est pas un emploi conj. mais où *malgré* est un subst. compl. de *j'en aie* et *que* le pron. rel.

Nonetheless, I've found [here](http://www.zcorrecteurs.fr/blog/billet-218-peut-on-dire-malgre-que.html) this statement:

> La question de « malgré que » est tout de même plus qu'une question d'usage.
>   Comme dit dans le Bon Usage, « Malgré que a été formé sur la préposition malgré, d'après le modèle de nombreuses locutions conjonctives correspondant à des prépositions (avant que, après que, dès que, sans que, etc.) ». La langue évolue et il n'y a rien d'étonnant dans le fait qu'une nouvelle locution conjonctive s'y `soit` insérée depuis quelques siècles déjà.
>
> L'Académie française et l'Éducation nationale qui applique ses recommandations sont en retard vis-à-vis de ce phénomène. Mais le temps fait étonnamment bien les choses.

And I started doubting because more often than not I find myself asking my French teacher questions to which the answer is most of the time "the French language has evolved and some rules don't really apply nowadays, they might be true, yes, but that's not how people talk on a daily basis and therefore it's pointless to fight it."

So my question is: is it okay to use *malgré que* here? Or should I use *malgré*? Or could I use *en depit de* interchangeably when in doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use *malgré que* you will suffer complaints from the normative French speakers the same way you would if you said *Je vais au coiffeur*. So to speak, it is your choice to use it or not knowing the consequence.

As mentioned in your last quote, French institutions are reluctant to acknowledge even reasonable evolutions so we end up with these situations where people argue against some expressions that are much more coherent with actual grammar than the norm without any substantial support for their "opinion".

Answer (score 1):

*Malgré que* with the meaning of "despite" does not exist and is a common mistake in the French language. The correct way to say it is "*malgré le fait que"*. Your sentence would be correct with "malgré le fait que".

> Une chose que j'ai bien aimé dans ce livre a été le message que **malgré le fait que** quelque chose soit vulnérable, petit ou apparemment impuissant...

*En dépit de* can be use interchangeably when you are in doubt.

Comment: "Malgré que" is not incorrect, but it is limited to specific cases, only with "avoir" (point 5 in Littré entry: http://www.littre.org/definition/malgr%C3%A9).

Comment: Well, actually it is only correct in the expression like "malgré que j’en aie", which means in this case "mal gré moi". If you look closely, it is said that the correct way to write it would be "mal gré" and it is not similar to the meaning of despite.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, *malgré que*  should not be used, you can use instead *bien que* that works in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

De manière communément admise et enseignée par (presque ?) tous les professeurs en France, **malgré que est incorrect dans la langue actuelle**.

Il y a bien d'autres formules possibles: **bien que**, **quoi que**, **malgré le fait que**, **en dépit du fait que** ...

L'usage de *malgré que*, **bien qu**'il soit incorrect, s'entend souvent, même régulièrement dans la bouche de journalistes.

Simple conseil de prudence: ne l'employez pas, sauf à revendiquer une licence poëtique, novatrice, *peuple* ...

*"Si j'avais su, j'aurais pas venu ..."*

Answer (score -1):

En ce qui concerne la France, Il faut éviter d'utiliser « malgré que » avec les personnes que l'on vouvoie.

You pointed it out in your question, and your french Feacher say it all. Language (even French) change.

I a highly formal conversation, or when writing an application for a job that requires French written communication skills, you should avoid using “malgré que”.

However, in every day conversation with French people, (and as long as your French accent is not perfect) you can use it.

If you know when to use “vous” or “tu” do not use “malgré que” and “vous”.

Comment: Cela n'a rien à voir avec le vouvoiement. Je doute que quiconque l'utilise fasse une exception pour certaines personnes ou même une situation particulière, *malgré* étant rarement utilisé dans un registre familier.