# Comment « bien » + « que » a-t-il pris le sens de « quoique » ?

Tags: étymologie, conjonctions

> [ [Wiktionnaire :](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bien_que#.C3.89tymologie) ] (Siècle à préciser) Composé de [bien](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bien#fr) et [que](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/que#fr).

Je ne comprends pas comment  « bien » ici engendre le sens de « quoique » dans « bien que ».

Ma conjecture: Bien que X, Y.
= Il est bon que X soit vrai, mais considérez Y car Y est plus important.

Comment: Ta conjecture est assez convaincante : "bien" dans le sens "bon, correct, valide". Ça parait plausible.

Answer (score 2):

***Bien*** a un sens positif, on admet comme réalité ce qui le suivra. Deux ellipses nous mènent directement à ces idées de reconnaissance de la réalité *X* et de son contraste avec la *« plus importante »* réalité *Y* :

> *[J’admets] bien que X, [mais néanmoins] Y*.

***Malgré*** contient aussi ce sens positif, même s’il inclut le préfixe « *mal-* » *(jllagre nous fait aussi remarquer que son usage est considéré comme incorrect par les puristes, et même dans une certaine mesure par plusieurs personnes; [discussion ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/202/malgr%C3%A9-que-est-il-correct))* :

> *Malgré que X, [néanmoins] Y*.

***Quoique*** peut s’interpréter comme « *en dépit de* », il implique une concession, et admet donc comme réalité la proposition qu’il introduit *(X)*, il en minimise simplement la portée ou l’importance en la contrastant avec la réalité *Y*, présentée par la suite. Un peu comme ***bien que***, somme toute.

> *Quoique X, [néanmoins] Y*.

---

#### En marge de la question

Même si *« bien que »* est très près de *« quoique »*, je crois qu’il existe une légère différence, le premier étant légèrement plus affirmatif que le second. Cette différence est généralement assez insensible, mais elle peut selon moi apparaître (subtilement) pour certains cas à la limite du réel :

> - *« **Bien que** l’on puisse admettre une certaine utilité aux horoscopes, on ne saurait raisonnablement croire à leurs prétendues fondations astrophysiques. »*
>     → Je semble reconnaître (au moins un peu) une certaine utilité aux horoscopes.
> - *« **Quoique** l’on puisse admettre une certaine utilité aux horoscopes, on ne saurait raisonnablement croire à leurs prétendues fondations astrophysiques. »*
>     → L’utilité des horoscopes est simplement reconnue comme possible, je ne me positionne pas vraiment sur la question. Le fait de ne pas se positionner affaiblit un peu l’affirmation.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/202/malgr%C3%A9-que-est-il-correct

Comment: Désolé, mais je ne pige pas comment votre réponse porte sur la question ?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal *«Bien»* introduit une réalité admise, ce qui est dans l'esprit du terme, et la contraste ensuite avec une réalité présentée comme plus forte. Un genre de compromis similaire à celui introduit par *«quoique». → **Bien qu**’il soit admis par la science que la Lune tourne autours de la Terre, on ne saurait pour autant placer cette dernière au centre de l’univers. — **Il est vrai** que la science admet que la Lune tourne autours de la Terre...* Si cela ne vous convient pas, je dois admettre mon incapacité à comprendre votre question convenablement. Désolé aussi.

Answer (score 0):

Une double conjecture :

1. Les apparences paraissent mettre X et Y en contradiction,
2. Quel que soit l'état (favorable ou contraire à mon raisonnement) de X, l'état de Y est inopérant sur la première conjecture.

N.B. : On peut aussi commencer les phrases par *Bien que* :

> *Bien que* le Wiktionnaire ne donne pas de phrase commençant par *bien que*, celles-ci sont correctes.

Answer (score 0):

> Quoiqu'il pleuve, il faut sortir

Est pareil que

> Bien qu'il pleuve, il faut sortir

Plus d'info ici: http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-9153.php

Comment: Désolé, mais je ne pige pas comment votre réponse porte sur la question ?