# Malgré que + indicatif

Tags: subjonctif, indicatif

On utilise le subjonctif avec « malgré que ». Mais dans quelle situation on peut utiliser l'indicatif ? Peut-on donner des exemples ?

Comment: Attention, `malgré que` est traditionnellement considéré comme faux, peut-être que la question porte plutôt sur les `bien que`, `quoique` et cie ?

Comment: Malgré que certains affirmeront le contraire, avec une question comme ça j'ai un peu peur qu'on tombe dans une controverse imbriquée.

Comment: il faut bien avouer que la plupart des gens éviteront de dire "malgré que". De par le fait "il a de petits pieds malgré qu'il est grand" ou "malgré qu'il soit grand" sonnent tous les deux aussi horriblement pour moi

Comment: @Julien *Malgré qu'il est grand* écorche deux fois plus mes oreilles que *malgré qu'il soit grand*...

Comment: @jilliagre: Je suis curieux. Pour « Je ne le qualifierais pas de remarquable, malgré qu'il est grand », nul, simple, double, ou peut-être triple écorchage des oreilles ?

Comment: @jiliagre les 2 écorchent en tout cas ;)

Comment: En effet, si *malgré que* a été utilisé à une époque, le moins qu'on puisse dire est qu'il est [tombé en désuétude](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=malgr%C3%A9+que&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmalgr%C3%A9%20que%3B%2Cc0). Je ne le recommanderais surtout pas à quelqu'un qui apprend le français, il risque de se faire corriger. Je ne me considère pas comme un "puriste" mais ça écorche mes oreilles comme c'est pas permis.

Comment: *Malgré que* étant considéré comme incorrect, et pas que par des puristes, le mode à utiliser à la suite (généralement le subjonctif) est surtout affaire d'opinion.

Comment: @jlliagre Voilà quelqu'un d'autre (à tort ou à raison) qui est affecté corporellement: ça écorche mes oreilles. Alors, si on a du mal à dire quelque chose, pourquoi pas: mal aux dents?

Comment: @Lambie Parce que les mots sont perçus par les oreilles, pas par les dents, non ?

Comment: @jlliagre Les mots sont dits par la bouche avec l'aide des dents.

Comment: @Lambie Les mots qui écorchent les oreilles sont ceux des autres. Si vraiment tu veux dire que tu souffrirais à les prononcer, la phrase attendue serait *Ces mots écorchent ma bouche*. Les dents sont accessoires dans la prononciation, les *sans-dents* peuvent parler aussi ;-)

Comment: @Lambie Et puis contrairement aux oreilles ou à la bouche, on ne peut pas, au sens propre, écorcher des dents, les dents n'ont pas de peau, les dents ne saignent pas.

Comment: @jlliagre Franchement, pas très sympa.

Answer (score 1):

Le point [B.2. du TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/malgr%C3%A9) donne en exemple:

> 2. [Avec l'ind.] Parler des jeunes gens qui t'ont suivi en 1830 et porté en triomphe, malgré que tu répondais à leurs cris de « Vive la Charte » par ceux de « Vive le Roi » (Mmede Chateaubr., Mém. et lettres,1847, p. 186).Quand j'les ai vus attigés, je me suis levé − malgré qu'on m'gueulait : « Couche-toi! » (Barbusse, Feu,1916, p. 38):
> 3. ... quand elle était partie, malgré que je lui promettais toujours d'être raisonnable, je tombais dans un si morne désespoir que, chaque fois, on craignait pour ma santé. G. Leroux, Parfum,1908, p. 16.

Answer (score 1):

See this [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33194/why-is-subjunctive-being-used-here/33196#33196) and references therein.

From [françaisfacile.com](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-25454.php):

> Indiquant une restriction, une opposition : on emploie le subjonctif.
> La restriction inverse la relation de cause attendue. Bien que Pierre
> soit venu, je suis sortie. Subjonctif car la venue de Pierre aurait dû
> me faire rester. C'est le décalage entre ce qui est attendu et ce qui
> se passe qui entraîne l'emploi du subjonctif.
>
> Certaines locutions formées avec que sont toujours suivies du
> subjonctif :
>
> à condition que, afin que, à moins que, à supposer que, au lieu que,
> bien que, d'aussi loin que, de crainte que, de façon que, de manière
> que, de peur que, du plus loin que, en admettant que, en attendant
> que, encore que, en sorte que, jusqu'à ce que, moyennant que, peu s'en
> est fallu que, pour autant que, pour peu que, pour que, pourvu que,
> quel que (et quelque... que), qui que, quoique (et quoi que), avant
> que , sans que, si bien que, si peu que, si tant est que, soit que...
> soit que, supposé que, trop... pour que

**> Malgré que: cette dernière est à éviter car impropre sauf lorsque

> cette locution est suivie d''avoir' -> malgré qu'il ait ... Néanmoins
> elle est employée de plus en plus régulièrement et doit être citée.
> Elle est obligatoirement suivie du subjonctif.**

[Another source (Académie française)](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#48_strong-em-malgr-que-em-strong)

> Malgré que : Malgré que s’emploie bien dans la langue
> soutenue, mais seulement avec le verbe avoir conjugué au subjonctif.
> Malgré que j’en aie, quelque mauvais gré, si mauvais gré que j’en aie
> ; en dépit de moi, de ma volonté : Je reconnais les mérites de mon
> rival, malgré que j’en aie ; Malgré qu’il en ait, nous savons son
> secret ; Elle ne put cacher son dépit, malgré qu’elle en eût.
>
> En revanche, encore que de nombreux écrivains aient utilisé la
> locution conjonctive Malgré que dans le sens de Bien que, quoique, il
> est recommandé d’éviter cet emploi.

Another pertinent question: [FSE](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/202/malgr%C3%A9-que-est-il-correct).

Comment: Êtes-vous conscient que l'indicatif est attesté par le TLFi (II.B.) pour cette locution ? Qu'est-ce que vous en pensez ?

Comment: @LPH Académie française vs TLFi et moi au milieu :-)! Que puis-je en penser ? Je sais ce vous dites mais vous vous rappelez que pas tout le monde n'a pas les mêmes idées. (5915961T's reply here https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33194/why-is-subjunctive-being-used-here/33196#33196)

Comment: J'aime la langue française et sa grammaire mais je n'ai pas étudié la Linguistique. S'il n'y a pas de cohérence entre TLFi et le site de l'Académie française, je ne peux que constater cette incohérence:-)!

Comment: @LPH voir la discussion ici https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/202/malgr%C3%A9-que-est-il-correct

Comment: De même, je ne peux que constater qu'il n'y a pas d'explications, pas de logique, seulement des« faites » et des « ne faites pas ». Je comprends que vous choisissez ce qui semble le plus sûr en attendant mieux. C'est une bonne façon de procéder! Merci pour les liens que vous venez de me  donner (FSE questions), leur contenu est plus instructif que les rapports des dictionnaires.

Comment: @LPH J'apprécie votre intérêt et le temps que vous avez consacré pour ouvrir mes horizons. Moi je trouve que vos idées (ici et les commentaires dans la discussion récente) méritent d'être publiées quelque part ; comme ce travail ici https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=9U66xqoK0nJk.html

Answer (score 0):

On peut penser que le subjonctif soit [obligatoire](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4238) avec cette locution (qui n'est toujours pas considérée comme du français standard par certains puristes) ; cependant le [TLFi, (II.B.)](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=2306228925;) indique la possibilité d'utilisation des deux modes et cet usage est en accord avec un point de vue moderne selon lequel le choix doit dépendre de la nature de l'action ou de l'état que le verbe implique ; le même principe est applicable avec les locution « bien que », « quoique » et « encore que », lesquelles lui sont synonymes.

> 1. **Indicatif** Il s'utilise lorsque l'action ou l'état sont réalisés dans le passé, le présent ou le futur.

En supposant que vous sachiez que la personne à qui un homme serre la main est bien son adversaire,  selon le point de vue avancé ci-dessus la phrase suivante en tant que dite à cet homme, est correcte.

- Il vous serre la main, malgré que vous êtes son adversaire. (Il n'y a aucune hypothèse quant à la réalité de la chose)

La phrase suivante, à laquelle on fournit facilement un contexte est correcte.

- Malgré que vous aurez ce taux d'intérêt assuré pendant vingt ans votre capital risque d'être dévalué, ce n'est pas un taux suffisamment élevé.

> 2. **Subjonctif** Il doit s'utiliser lorsque l'action ou l'état que le verbe confère est considéré non dans un cas spécifique en tant qu'action ou état réalisé ou dont on est sûr qu'ils le seront, mais comme seulement hypothétique.

Reprenant l'exemple au «1.», on suppose maintenant que sur la base de la connaissance d'une personne qui serre la main à ses ennemis, vous vouliez formuler cet état de chose de façon générale ; alors le pronom « vous » dans cette phrase n'est plus quelqu'un en particulier mais une personne hypothétique, et il faut donc le subjonctif.

- Il vous serre la main, malgré que vous soyez son adversaire.

  Il y a dans ce cas une base hypothétique : « seriez-vous son adversaire il vous serrerait quand même la main ».

Il faut faire au moins une distinction lorsque il s'agit de la réalité de l'action ou de l'état ;  cela a rapport aux actions ou états habituels, pour lesquels on utilise le présent. L'exemple suivant sert à voir ce détail.

- En hiver, malgré qu'il y a du verglas, il roule quand même trop vite.

On pourrait arguer que prononcer cette phrase en été ou même un jour d'hiver sans verglas résulte en une référence à un état qui n'existe pas au moment où on parle ; ce n'est pas ainsi ; au moment où l'on parle l'état de chose « verglas présent sur les routes l'hiver » est vrai ; on voit le même principe dans le verbe « rouler » qui est conjugué au **présent habituel**. Cependant, on trouvera que le subjonctif est souvent utilisé dans ce cas  ; cela est indubitable au vu de la règle d'emploi du subjonctif avec « malgré que » selon la BDL (voir référence ci-dessus). Un tel exemple peut être vérifié dans le TLFi :

« Il a fait beau et clair, même il faisait déjà presque chaud, malgré qu'à ces hauteurs les matinées ordinairement soient assez fraîches. ». (Ramuz, Gde peur,1926, p. 49.)

Comment: Tout, même une réalité, peut être considéré comme une hypothèse. Le rôle du subjonctif c'est justement de ne pas formuler de jugement, ni de porter l'attention dessus, seulement de définir. Ce serait un comble de « devoir » utiliser l'indicatif lorsque une hypothèse s'applique. Contrairement à ce que ta réponse laisserait penser, l'indicatif est le mode inhabituel dans de telles subordonnées. Il est rare, car le contenu de ces subordonnées est rarement sujet à discussion.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Il faudrait que vous spécifiez l'élément exact dans mon texte qui supporte votre assertion.

Comment: « En hiver, il y a du verglas ». C'est une hypothèse que tout le monde admet (ou en tout cas que le locuteur considère admise), ce n'est pas à prendre comme une information nouvelle de sa part. Ça devient donc un subjonctif sans qu'on ait à se soucier de savoir si c'est « vrai » ou « faux » ou « réel » ou « sûr ». Personne ne s'attend à ce que cette hypothèse soit remise en cause.

Comment: De même « vous êtes son adversaire » peut être avancé comme une hypothèse (pourquoi dire que ce n'en est pas une ?). C'est une hypothèse lorsque ce n'est pas le sujet des propos avancés.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Nous ne sommes pas d'accord sur le sens du mot « hypothèse » : selon ma compréhension il ne s'agit aucunement d'hypothèse mais d'un fait ; « il y a du verglas en hivers est un fait. » est l'assertion d'un fait ; Une hypothèse  se formule le plus simplement possible au moyen du verbe « supposer » ou bien  «imaginer » ; on ne suppose pas qu'il y a du verglas en hiver (en Europe), on le sait ; ce n'est pas tout le temps, mais dans les régions du Nord, un jour ou l'autre il faut qu'il y ait du verglas.

Comment: Oulà en effet on n'est pas d'accord. [Hypo-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypo-), [Thesis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thesis).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez ,Oui, cela **peut** être avancé comme une hypothèse, et alors vous choisissez le subjonctif ; néanmoins, si vous savez qu'il s'agit d'un adversaire, vous ne pouvez pas nier cela en prétendant que c'est une hypothèse et en utilisant à cause de cela le subjonctif ; comme vous savez, vous utilisez l'indicatif. Il y a un petit problème concernant ce « vous » : je le veux dans mon explication comme signifiant « une personne en général et pas celle à qui on s'adresse en particulier » mais on peut très bien le considérer comme signifiant l'interlocuteur, et cela ne change rien.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88021/discussion-between-lph-and-stephane-gimenez).

Comment: Quelle est la logique qui fait répondre à une question portant sur l'usage de l'indicatif et du subjonctif en commençant par une phrase où le subjonctif est utilisé de manière fautive à la place de l'indicatif ?